# Install .deb packages into mounted fs

Tags: linux, debian, mount, dpkg

I have a ext2 partition on CF card to use in external device. I've inserted this card into my PC and mount it as /mnt/linux. I've installed (extracted) a linux distribution to this partition.
And I want to add some .deb packages to this partition. How should I do this? Is it possible?

The alternative way I use: I copy .deb packages into /mnt/linux/tmp dir, then insert CF card into external device, and install `cd /tmp; dpkg -i XXX.deb` from this device.

Comment: Do a `chroot /mnt/linux` and instal there? (Would need the `deb` machinery in there, perhaps mounted from the outside). This more or less assumes you have a full Debian installtion in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As vonbrand suggested, assuming you have a working Debian install on the CF card, you should be able to `chroot` to it and install normally:

```
sudo chroot /mnt/linux
sudo dpkg -i XXX.deb
```

Comment: This is the command I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: But how can I change the base_os archive, without mounting CF card? I have a base os for CF-card in `base_os.tgz` file, then I put it into mounted (in /mnt/linux) CF-card via `tar zxvf base_os.tgz -C /mnt/linux`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, for the `chroot` to work, you need to `chroot` to a directory that contains a working Linux system (things like `/bin/bash` etc).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the --root option of dpkg to specify the directory where the target root filesystem is mounted.

In your case:

```
sudo dpkg --install --root=/mnt/linux XXX.deb
```

I've found that this invocation may produce the following error (not sure if this is a dpkg bug, or something related to the filesystem I'm using):

```
dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: No such file or directory
```

The workaround is to use the --admindir option to specify the var/lib/dpkg. In your case:

```
sudo dpkg --install --root=/mnt/linux --admindir=/mnt/linux/var/lib/dpkg XXX.deb
```

This solution helps if you are building the filesystem and you cannot perform a chroot because the target filesystem is incomplete.